# How to change and retrieve HTML document

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

I'm using JQuery npm within NodeJS to try to process some HTML. But I can't seem to get the final html as text to send down the pipe with the http module. I can get `$html.find('head')` to yield html text, but `$html.find('html')` and all other solutions yield an object.

Here's my code:

```
// this code, which will run under nodejs using jquery, should update the head in an entire html document

var $ = require('jquery');
var $html = $('<html><head><title>this should be replaced</title></head><body>and the entire document should be available as text</body></html>');
console.log('html', $html);
var $body = $html.find('body');

var res = $html.find('head').replaceWith('<head><title>with this</title></head>');
console.log(res.html());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wb7yV/4/

thanks!

Comment: BTW, `$html.find('head')` doesn't yield any HTML text.

Answer (score 0):

When you view the console log on `$html` you'll notice it contains 2 indexed objects: `title` and `text`. While viewing those objects, notice that neither have any children, which functions such as [`jQuery.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) are designed to browse.

> **Description:** Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

A [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for 'title' or 'text' will allow you to select the individual elements as needed.

```
var $html = $('<html><head><title>this should be replaced</title></head><body>and the entire document should be available as text</body></html>');
var $title = $html.filter('title');
var $body = $html.filter('text');

var res = $title.html('replace with this');
console.log(res.filter('title').html());
// returns: "replace with this"
```

Comment: thanks, but my goal is not to replace the title, which already works. My goal is to retrieve the html text after I do a number of replacements.

Comment: @davidm, This is still done the same way as you were doing it, but because you don't have any DOM descendants, you can't use `find` on the string you created. But you can still select them before and after you've replaced the text. Just use `filter` instead and view the `console.log(object)` to see what nodes you can filter on.

Comment: @davidm, I've edited the code to demonstrate how it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close with your jsfiddle.
To change the head, just use this:

```
$('head').html('<title>with this</title>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Going strictly with what you've posted, you can see `$html` is an Object array with two entires. If you run `var res = $html[1];
console.log(res.textContent);`, you can get the text of the body. But not sure if this is what you're after?